# What is the difference for these words for "which"?

Tags: pronouns, interrogative

There are three main choices for expressing the idea of "which" in Latin:

```
qui 
quinam 
quisnam
```

How do you choose which one to use in which situation? So, I am asking both for interrogatives and relative pronouns.

Comment: Are you looking for interrogative uses only or also relative? It might also help if you have some concrete uses cases in mind. Depending on what you are after, the best option can be something not on your list (e.g. "which one of these two things?").

Comment: Agreed. Which uses of 'which,' which are different from each other, did you have in mind?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I am only asking about the differences between the words listed.

Comment: I edited your title to better get across what you're asking, I believe (coming off your last comment).

Answer (score 5):

Your main words that roughly correspond to the English "which" are:

- the relative pronoun *qui*
- the adjective interrogative *qui* (identical to the relative pronoun in every way)
- the substantive interrogatives *quis* and *quid*

You use the relative pronoun when you are making a relative clause, e.g. *Speculator, qui me amavit*. You can also use it adjectively, which is possible in English as well, but tends to sound stilted (*Ania, quam speculatricem amavi*).

You use the interrogatives when asking a question. For persons, it's *quis*: *Quis me amat? Quem amo?* (gender makes no difference). For things, it's *quid*: *Quid est veritas?* Adjectively, it's *qui*: *Quae speculatrix me amavit? Quo modo feram eius mortem?* All this is also true for indirect questions: *Quis sim, numquam scies.*

But you will also see usages like *quis vir* or *qui rogat?* So the rule for adjectival and substantival use is not always adhered to.

The postfix *-nam* can be added both to interrogative *qui* and *quis/quid* to put an extra emphasis on the question: *Quisnam es?* ("Who, pray, are you?") or *Quaerunt quonam pacto mortem amici feras* ("They want to know just how you are bearing your friend's death").

This was only a short overview. See more details in [Allen & Greenough](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/relative-interrogative-and-indefinite-pronouns), or another grammar book of your choice.

Comment: I am asking specifically about the three words I listed, as it says in the question.

Comment: @TylerDurden I believe my answer has those three covered.